# React POST/GET fake-json server ID generating dilemma

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm using fake-json server as DB.

Problem: when I POST {text} into DB onSubmit , I have to GET all the data again to retrieve id, because when I setState on new data, I don't include id as parameter, as fake-json DB automatically generates ID. So If I don't refetch data, my new added objects are without id parameter, and I can't manipulate individual text object by ID (like toggling etc.)

so my question is, is this option is viable ? because it seems like escape hatch.

Thank you !

fakejson.db

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "text": "Test1",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "text": "Test2",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "text": "Test3",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
    data: [],
    text: '',
}

 apiCall = (method,body) => {
   return fetch('http://localhost:4000/data', {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    method,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
}

 handleAddInputChange = event => {
        this.setState({text: event.target.value})
    }



handleAddFormSubmit = event => {
    const {text, data} = this.state
    event.preventDefault()

    const text = { text }



this.setState({data: [...data, text], text: ''})

 apiCall('POST', text)
 apiCall('GET').then(data => this.setState({data}))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by myself, that  would be `apiCall('POST, newText).then(newText => this.setState({text:[...text,newText]}))`